# React Native - Firebase EmailAuthProvider undefined

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, undefined

I have been trying to reauthenticate a user using the following line:

```
firebase
.auth()
.currentUser
.reauthenticateWithCredential(
    firebase
    .auth
    .EmailAuthProvider
    .credential(
        firebase
        .auth()
        .currentUser
        .email, providedPassword
    )
)
```

However, strangely I am bumping into undefined error:
[image]

Was trying to find a solution why it might be undefined but still no success. Has anybody dealt with this problem before?

Comment: one of those props is a function I think. Have you tried to console log each chain what value it is?

Comment: I have tried everything separately, but somehow EmailAuthProvider seems to be undefined only. This is really strange for me. Any idea why it might bug like that?